# How to correctly configure Azure Static Web App with Create React App and react router v6

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-router, create-react-app, azure-static-web-app

I have a react app which is using create react app and react router v6. It's being deployed to Azure Static Web App via github action.

.yml file for the action looks like this

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - feature/*

jobs:
    build_and_deploy_job:
        if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        name: Build and Deploy Job
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
              with:
                  submodules: true
            - name: Build And Deploy
              id: builddeploy
              uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
              with:
                  azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
                  repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
                  action: 'upload'
                  ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
                  # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
                  app_location: '/' # App source code path
                  api_location: 'api' # Api source code path - optional
                  output_location: 'build' # Built app content directory - optional
                  ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
              env:
                  ...

    close_pull_request_job:
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        name: Close Pull Request Job
        steps:
            - name: Close Pull Request
              id: closepullrequest
              uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
              with:
                  azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
                  action: 'close'
```

As for the app itself, it's fairly simple for now, with handful of routes so far:

```
const AppRoutes = () => {
    return (
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<GlobalLayout />}>
                        <Route index element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
                        <Route path="/orders" element={<Orders />} />
                        <Route path="/orders/:oid" element={<ProjectDetails />} />
                        <Route path="/helpcenter" element={<HelpCenter />} />

                        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
                    </Route>
                    {/* <Route index element={<Home />} /> */}
                </Routes>
    );
};
```

Locally, everything works. Also, deployed to Azure everything works, when the app is accessed from the root domain, ie `myapp.com`

The problem occurs when I try to access it via `myapp.com/orders/3`. Then it throws page not found 404.

Then I realized i need `staticwebapp.config.json` file, to tell Azure to let my app handle the routing.

Content of `staticwebapp.config.json` which is located in my app's root file looks like this:

```
{
    "navigationFallback": {
        "rewrite": "/index.html",
        "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/static/*"]
    }
}
```

After adding it, it loads my app, but shows a blank page. In the console it shows the following errors:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://myaapp.com/orders/static/css/main.d7af2528.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'https://myapp.com/orders/static/js/main.4af7cbd5.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

So obviously, it's accessing the js and css files relativley.

What am I missing in configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the following `staticwebapp.config.json`:

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": ["/static/media/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp}",   "/static/css/*"]
  },
  "mimeTypes": {
    ".json": "text/json"
  }
}
```

I have the exact setup and when I deployed the app using [`SWA CLI`](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/cli/swa-deploy/), it created the above file automatically and placed it in the app's root folder.

**So where to place this config json file?**

https://medium.com/@elnoor/react-client-side-routing-in-azure-static-web-app-299c8ba96fb8

Since you deploy the production build of React app, this json file will need to be part of build. Assuming the React-App is used to create the React app, file has to be placed in public folder. While building the app everything in public folder will be in build folder too. So staticwebapp.config.json file will be next to index.html file in the root directory of the built app.

[image]